# How to freeze an iteration in loop for printing python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, printing

if i have:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...... ]
names = ['aaron', 'adrian', 'alan', 'brian', 'cathy', 'coby' .... ] #sorted by alphabet
```

How can i get output to look as:

```
a - aaron, adian, alan,
b - brian,
c - cathy, coby, ....
.....
.....
```

I tried:

```
  for letter in alphabet:
       print("")
       for name in names:
            if name[0] == letter:
            print(letter, " - ", name, sep=' ', end=', ', flush=True)
```

but It didnt work. So i want a way to freeze "letter" so it doesn't appear next to every single name.

Comment: What do you mean by "freezing"

Comment: `from itertools import groupby;` then run `for i, j in groupby(names, key = lambda x: x[0]):print(i,'-', *j)`

Comment: i dont know how to ask the question but if you check the output you will know what i mean

Comment: x here is the alphabet?

Comment: No. Look at the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

```
for letter in alphabet:
       print(letter, ' - ', end = '')
       for name in names:
            if name[0] == letter:
                print(name, sep = ', ', end = ', ')
       print()
```

You could also do:

```
from itertools import groupby
for letter, names in groupby(names, key = lambda x: x[0]):
    print(letter ,'-', ', '.join(names))
```

Comment: just one thing, the second code worked perfectly, since it didnt add alphabets that has no names in the list associated with that alphabet, but the first code printed the alphabet even though there were no names in the list that are associated with that alphabet